# List Preference or Shared Preference?

Tags: android

If I have a listview extending the list activity , and creating a check list (simple_item_checked). Is it better to use List Preference to save the checked value or Shared Preference to save the value?

I also have a small doubt on setting up shared preference for the list view activity. I am passing the list item row position and the boolean value of that row ( is checked or not) to the shared preference using getInt and getBoolean . Is it right? Or should I have to include or pass any other parameters apart from this to ensure that the proper row is checked ? Some one please help me .

I have a doubt on List Preference because as far as I've seen , list preferences are used only for the setting screens. Like our android setting screen. Can we also use the same for a simple list item checked to store the checked state of an item in the list.

```
    public class Secondact extends ListActivity {
    ListView list;
    SharedPreferences pref;
     int pos,itemposition,positionvalue;
     boolean boolval,checkvalue;
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          // setContentView(R.layout.secondact);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ONCREATE", 50).show();

            list=getListView();

           String[] family_array=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.family);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,family_array);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
           list.setChoiceMode(1);
           pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
         pos=pref.getInt("itempos", pos);
             boolval=pref.getBoolean("boolvalue", true);
            list.setItemChecked(pos, boolval);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA LOADED ITEM NO:"+pos, 50).show();

           list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                pos=position;
                list.setItemChecked(pos, true);
                pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                editor=pref.edit();
                editor.putInt("itempos", pos);
                editor.putBoolean("boolvalue", list.isItemChecked(pos));
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     editor=pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("itempos", pos);
        editor.putBoolean("boolvalue", list.isItemChecked(pos));
        editor.commit();
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PAUSE", 50).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
         pos=pref.getInt("itempos", pos);
         boolval=pref.getBoolean("boolvalue", true);
        list.setItemChecked(pos, boolval);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RESUME", 50).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
         editor=pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("itempos", pos);
        editor.putBoolean("boolvalue", list.isItemChecked(pos));
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DESTROY", 50).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA SAVED ITEM NO:"+pos, 50).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     pos=pref.getInt("itempos", pos);
         boolval=pref.getBoolean("boolvalue", true);
        list.setItemChecked(pos, boolval);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RESTART", 50).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        savedInstanceState.putInt("itempositionno", positionvalue);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("checkvalue", true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ONSAVEINSTANCE", 50).show();
        list.setItemChecked(pos, checkvalue);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        pos=savedInstanceState.getInt("itempositionno", pos);
         checkvalue=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("checkvalue", true);
        list.setItemChecked(pos, checkvalue);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ONRESTOREINSTANCE", 50).show();
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }




}
```

Comment: `ListPreferece` is a `Preference` that saves the value to `SharedPreferences` automatically.

Comment: So does that mean I can use ListPreference in place of a SharedPreferences for saving ListView Item Checked ??

Comment: Caps lock is not a good way to emphasize text, especially not in the title.

Comment: Okay sorry. But I am new to this forum. Didn't know that.

Comment: @Krish3090 - ListPreference is not made for saving a list of preferences (as the name may imply). It's meant to display a list of options (Option A, Option B, Option C, etc) and letting the user select a single one, and then automatically saving that option to shared preferences. In your case, you will need to use SharedPreferences

Comment: How is your `ListView' extending a 'ListActivity'?

Comment: @dymmeh: Thanks bro ! That is what I exactly wanted. Also if I have to save a value in the listview if an item is checked. Is it enough if I pass the integer value (row of the list) and boolean value(checked state) to the Shared Preferences ? Or do I need to save something more ?

Comment: @OrhanC1 : Bro that's a normal method name I had given. I didn't mean to say ListView keyword. Probably you can take that as SecondActivity.

Comment: @Krish3090 So you have something like `MyListViewActivity extends ListViewActivity` ?

Comment: Exactly ! Bingo ! Now I wanted to save the checked list item. I need to know which parameters should I pass to save and retrieve while using Shared Preferences.

Comment: @Krish3090 - is your list always the same? will it ever change? If its always the same you can just save the position that is checked (integer)

Comment: @dymmeh : Yeah its always the same. I did as you said. But the problem is, 
I have 2 Activities. 
1. Main Page with a button that gets the user to the check list.
2.Checklist page where the user checks an option.
Now when I open the app , Main page is seen by the user.The user clicks on the button and gets to the listpage. Now he sets the checked value. But when he returns back after closing the app completely to the second page then the checked item is unchecked. This is the problem I'm facing. Will be thankful if you really help me out. I would post the code if you want to.Let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use a ListPreference here.
You can either save the list of preference as a file or can use the shared preference.
it will be better to use sharedPreference as it is pretty fast and easy.

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList;

                SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("shared_check_prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pref.edit();
                    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
                        edit.putBoolean("CECK_PREFS"+i, value);
                        edit.commit();
                    }
```

The code to get the preference of the checkbox at row =i will be

SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("shared_check_prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                pref.getBoolean("CECK_PREFS"+i,false);

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Will try this and let you know.Hope it works out.Out of curiosity, why do we have "CECK_PREFS"+i in the preference string ? any specific reason. And should this code snippet be inserted inside the onlistitemclick listener method ?? If not where am i suppose to put this code?

Comment: Just now thought about it. So the i in "CECK_PREFS"+i means it saves the preference value of each row in the list. Gotcha.. But do tell me where should i save and retrieve my preference. Is it enough if I give put the preference in ONPAUSE method and retrieve the values during ONRESUME method ??? And the number in the expression i<number means the string array length right ? so it should be like i<array.length ? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: yes. You are right. you can access the preference from any where in your application , and all you need is the Tag used for creating the SharedPreference (here shared_check_prefs) and the key used for saving the preference. ie CHECK_PREFS+i

Comment: Great thanks mate !but i tried with storing the item row and item boolean value.I am in my MainActivity then I click a button and go to the next activity where I have my simple_list_item_checked. Now I click a value in the list. It gets saved. But my problem is when I revisit the same list and press back to go to the main acitivity  without changing the checked value. My value gets lost in the shared preference. The next time I visit the activity nothing is checked. Can you tell me what might be the problem ? If you want I can include the code in the question above.Please help me mate!

Comment: I have added the code in the question mate ! Please go through and help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it seems you have only one variable to save. The position of the checked button. because you are getting only one pair of variables in onCreate(0, ie "itempos" and boolValue. Am I right?

Comment: yes absolutely right bro! Now is it the right way to do ? But i still have the problem of my shared preference value getting reset. How do I deal with this problem ? :(

Comment: No. Just add a ListPreference.It's the easiest way for this. I thought you have a list of values to save.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the information bro. Will let you know once I complete this application. :)

Comment: @Krish3090 ok. All the best bro.

Comment: Thanks Mate! Appreciate that ! Will let you know once I am about to release this app on the play market. Do give your feedback and suggestions on the same, since this is my first application that I am developing on. :) Cheers !